# General approach for displaying a message on any page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a fairly simple (to explain) requirement for my ASP.NET MVC web application:

> On any page, be able to display a message based on an event that happened on a preceding page. Messages may include dynamic content, such as information entered by the user in a form submission.
>
> Similar to this...
>
> [image: Yes, success!]
>
> The approach must work in [POST-REDIRECT-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) scenarios.
>
> If the user has two browser tabs (which share session state) open on the application, then any message should only be displayed in the tab in which the related event happened.
>
> For example:
>
> - After submitting a feedback form, a message thanking the user (by name)
> - When logging in, a message telling the user the date/time when they last logged in to the application

My first thought was to use a strongly-typed view with an appropriate model (with a `string` property) for this. However this would mean changing every single existing non-strongly-typed view to use this model, and updating all existing models to inherit from this new model.

This seems like overkill.

An alternative is to store the message in `TempData`:

```
// In my controller
TempData["Message"] = "Some kind of message";

// In my shared master view
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <div class="message">@TempData["Message"]</div>
}
```

Using `TempData` is covered in a bit more detail in [this blog posting](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/). Interestingly, the author also suggests using a custom HTTP header as an alternative. An interesting idea, but [does not work with POST-REDIRECT-GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003628/how-to-add-headers-on-a-302-redirect-in-asp-net-mvc).

Is using `TempData` the preferred option, or is there a "better" alternative? (e.g. something more strongly typed)

Answer (score 2):

> My first thought was to use a strongly-typed view with an appropriate model (with a string property) for this. However this would mean changing every single existing non-strongly-typed view to use this model, and updating all existing models to inherit from this new model.

This is the only consistent, reusable, testable solution to do this that I can imagine, despite the extra work it may cause.

Comment: @RichardEv you're right, I think I missed that requirement. So actually you're just looking for a "GET with side-effects"?

Comment: (In which case it is a duplicate of [Post-Redirect-Get (PRG) Summary Page on Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775684/post-redirect-get-prg-summary-page-on-submit) and others).

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to use `ViewModels` to communicate between `View` and `Controllers`. You can have a base `View Model` and all other `View Models derived from that` as below:

```
   public class BaseVM
    {
       public string Message{ get; set;}
    }

    public class CreateViewModel: BaseVM
    {
       public string CustoomerName{ get; set;}
    }
```

You can populate the `Message` property while returning the model to the controller as below:

```
public ActionResult Step2()
{
   //Some Logic

    step2Model.Message = "Yes, Success..!!";

    return View(step2Model);
}
```

After that, on each view page, you can check if that property has something in it.You can do so as below:

```
 @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Message))
{
  //Show message
}
```

**EDIT:**

OP is well  aware of this approach, but still keeping this answer as it has a snippet to show how to do this in code. Secondly, when it comes to use ViewModels, I agree with following comment by CodeCaster in his answer.

> This is the only consistent, reusable, testable solution to do this that I can imagine, despite the extra work it may cause.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a convention in your project that a message to display would always go into `ViewBag.InfoMessage` dynamic variable. So, in your layout file you would display it if it's passed into the view from a controller.

More strict way would be to create a base model class with `InfoMessage` property and derive all other models / viewmodels from that base.

To persist the message through POST-REDIRECT-GET scenario, use a session variable which you'd clear once the value is sent to the view - to avoid displaying on more than one page.

Here some code:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public string InfoMessage { get; set; }
}
public class SpecificViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // other model properties
}
```

In your controller then:

```
SpecificViewModel vm = new SpecificViewModel();

vm.InfoMessage = Session["InfoMessage"] as string;
Session["InfoMessage"] = null;

// other code

return View(vm);
```

Of course your view will have strongly typed model: `SpecificViewModel`.

Comment: A code sample would be great. I just attempted this in a POST-REDIRECT-GET scenario and the `ViewBag` data did not persist past the redirect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I somewhat missed the requirement for POST-REDIRECT-GET in your question. For that you'd probably better off to use session variables to persist messages between pages. Then, you'd use that value in the describbed way: either in a `ViewBag` or a base model class. I'll post some code and update the answer.